# Enumerable.Empty<T>() equivalent for IList?

Tags: c#, .net, list, ienumerable

In some case I've to return an empty list of items in a method.
Most of the case, I'm returning an `IEnumerable<T>`, so the `Enumerable.Empty<T>()` does exactly the job.

But I've one case where I've to return absolutely an `IList<T>` instance(we could use an IEnumerable, but this would results in a code much less efficient).

I didn't found an equivalent for the `IList`. I can perfectly imagine doing my own Singleton provider for empty list, but I would like to know if there is something I did miss?

Comment: why do you say code would be less efficient ?

Comment: Check this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6802982/6469077

Comment: return new List<T>()

Comment: @Vignesh.N Because I will normally have a lot of items, and I will have to remove some of them in the list, so it means that I will have to create a List from the IEnumerable to start to works with.

Comment: @heinzbeinz and @TimSchmelter: The goal is not have to create this object on each case but to have an empty object that could be reused, like the `Enumerable.Empty<T>()`.

Answer (score 27):

As Array is implementing IList use

```
Array.Empty<T>()
```

Comment: Additional info: This only works if you are using .net 4.6 or newer.